# Why Isn't Linking Work Items working in VSTS Wiki

Tags: azure-devops, wiki

I'm editing a wiki page and trying to [link to a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/markdown-guidance#links) but nothing popups up when I enter '#', why not?

[image: work item linking not working]

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't see how this is a programming question. Wouldn't this be something to ask VSTS about? This seems like a product support question and not a programming one.

Comment: @Lexi while it's not a programming question, "software tools commonly used by programmers" is explicitly _on topic_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VSTS Wiki now supports referencing work items using #](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/10/16/wiki-to-turn-wiki-many-exciting-features/). You can type # and reference an existing work item. This feature has just been completed and is still being deployed as I type.

Very soon, you will be able to link a wiki to a work item. Imagine this feature allowing you to track what % of your epic is completed when you refer each feature of the epic on your wiki page.

You can try and share your feedback.